# What's wrong with the following code on ruby continuation?

Tags: ruby

New to ruby here. Tried to write a simple ruby code to do continuation, but the following code will print non-stopping integers 2,3, 4, 5, 6 ... (one number in each line).  There must be an obvious bug here.  Thanks.

```
require "continuation"

def dum ()
    i = 1
    callcc {|cc| $c = cc}
    i += 1
    puts i
end

dum()   #expect to print 2
$c.call #expect to print 3
$c.call #expect to print 4
```

My ruby interpreter is 1.9.3p0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c.call makes a complete jump back to the set execution context, so your script is repeatedly alternating between the call to dum() and the first line invoking $c.call, never reaching the last line. Here's the flow:

1. The `dum()` method is defined
2. `dum()   #expect to print 2`: The script invokes `dum()` once, which sets an execution context for `$c` and then prints `2`
3. `$c.call #expect to print 3` jumps back into the call to `dum()` from the previous line -- the top level context of execution literally moves back to the previous line. This time `dum()` prints 3
4. The script now reaches the same `$c.call #expect to print 3` line AGAIN, and will continue to infinitely alternate between these two lines.

The script will never reach your last line `$c.call #expect to print 4`.

One way to modify your script so that it produces the expected output:

```
require "continuation"

def dum ()
    i = 1
    callcc {|cc| $c = cc}
    i += 1
    puts i
    return i
end

k = dum()   #expect to print 2
$c.call unless k >= 4 # reach this line 3 times: print 3, and then 4, and then move on
```

I hope this helps.